# Using Unity Remote 5 for Unity 2017

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I want to test my Unity game with my Android device. But it seems there is no connection.

I use a **Huawei P9 Lite**

I activate the **developer mode** and connect my device with the computer. My device shows the message "**debugging mode is active**"

In Unity I go to the settings **Edit -> Project Settings -> Editor** and set "**Any Android Device**"

I started two tests

> Start the engine after running the app

and

> Run the engine first, start the app

When starting the game in Unity nothing happens on my device. Even when waiting some seconds, nothing comes up.

Comment: I don't have any problem using [this solution](https://answers.unity.com/questions/198853/unity-remote-for-android-not-working-solution.html)

Comment: By the way, you run Remote app first before running your Unity app. If `adb devices` cannot see the device, it won't work. The fist duplicate link shows how to setup the device and make sure that adb can see it. The second duplicate link shows how to restart adb server  if first one did not  work

Comment: i set up every thing for adb to detect my device, but it couldn't! found a solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52711048/6046022